# Invalidating the established SSL connections in OkHttp and react-native android apps

Tags: react-native, ssl, okhttp

React-native is using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) underneath to resolve the requests by the browser's `fetch` object and by default, it rejects the connections over self-signed/invalid certificates.

In this scenario, I'm required to implement the possibility to toggle between trusting all certificates and the default behavior as the users' choose at run-time. It's been achieved by overriding the default `OkHttpClientFactory` and implementing your logic in the `TrustManager` you use to bypass/restrict the invalid certificates.

Here's the TrustManager interface which has been used to override the SSL certificates validation logic.

```
public interface X509TrustManager extends TrustManager {

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
        throws CertificateException;

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
        throws CertificateException;

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers();
}
```

So basically every time a request is emitted, `checkServerTrusted` is called and once the method doesn't throw a `CertificateException` the request is passed through. The problem I encountered is that once you make a successful request to an SSL-enabled server(**https**://example.org), OkHttp refuses to call the `checkServerTrusted` method for a couple of seconds (4, 5 seconds by default). I'm assuming there's some sort of a cache that keeps the TLS connections alive for a few seconds. Consequently, the app is unable to change between the two modes unless you wait for a few seconds before you can turn TrustAllCerts option effectively back off.

What I've tried to invalidate those presumed live connections is the following methods every time we switch between the two modes:

```
OkHttpClient client = OkHttpClientProvider.getOkHttpClient();

client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
client.connectionPool().evictAll();
client.cache().close();
```

but I don't have any indication that any of the above methods are effective.

Also, I've tried to adjust the `OkHttpClientFactory` once the custom `OkHttpClient` is initialized guessing this might be an effect of *connectTimeout* or *connectTimeout*. Still no luck yet.

```
return new OkHttpClient
                    .Builder()
                    /* ... */
                    .cookieJar(new ReactCookieJarContainer())
                    .connectTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                    .build();
```

Plus, I checked the Android's LOGCAT and apparently, a cached version of the request is being used. So maybe the issue roots back to the prior time OkHttp becoms active.

Any ideas?